# Getting routes on openstreetmaps using OSRM

Tags: openstreetmap, osrm

I've been trying to get a list of co-ordinates in a route from point A to B using OSRM with the following request:

GET http://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute?hl=en&loc=47.064970,15.458470&loc=47.071100,15.476760

However, on opening the url, i find the 'via_points' tag containing only two co-ordinates. Surely, that can't be the entire route? Anything I'm missing here? Is there any other way of generating the list of route co-ordinates with OSRM? Thanks

Comment: Please use the new API. The old endpoint will be deprecated soon. What you want is `result.routes[0].overview` with paramaters `overview=full` and then decode with https://github.com/mapbox/polyline

Answer (score 1):

The route is contained in the `route_geometry` object. It is an [encoded polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm). If you don't want to uncompress it yourself you can disable compression via `compression=false`:

http://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute?compression=false&hl=en&loc=47.064970,15.458470&loc=47.071100,15.476760

Not sure what the `via_points` contains. OSRM's [documentation](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/docs/http.md) seems to be outdated. Maybe they are just your start and end points snapped to the nearest road or something similar.

Comment: The documentation is up to date, your are just using the old API. For the new version >=5 the request would look as follows: http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/15.458470,47.064970;15.476760,47.071100

Comment: A little confused. do i use overview=full or overview=false? what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

The URL `/viaroute` listed in the question and the other answer is deprecated. Instead you should use the URL `/route` as shown in the simple demo below:

[image: OpenstreetMap with 2 markers and OSRM route]

```js
'use strict';

function processOsrmReply(data) {

  if (data.code === 'Ok') {
    data.routes.forEach(function(route) {
      routesGroup.addData(route.geometry);
    });

    myMap.flyToBounds(routesGroup.getBounds());
  }
}

function sendOsrmRequest() {
  routesGroup.clearLayers();

  var url = 'https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/car/' +
    parseFloat(startMarker.getLatLng().lng).toFixed(6) + ',' +
    parseFloat(startMarker.getLatLng().lat).toFixed(6) + ';' +
    parseFloat(finalMarker.getLatLng().lng).toFixed(6) + ',' +
    parseFloat(finalMarker.getLatLng().lat).toFixed(6) +
    '?overview=simplified' +
    '&alternatives=3' +
    '&steps=false' +
    '&annotations=false' +
    '&geometries=geojson';

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.onload = function() {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
      processOsrmReply(data);
    }
  };
  request.send();
}

var startPosition = [47.064970, 15.458470];
var finalPosition = [47.071100, 15.476760];

var myMap = L.map('myMap').setView(startPosition, 14);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(myMap);

var markersGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(myMap);
var routesGroup = L.geoJSON().addTo(myMap);

var overlays = {
  'Show start and finish markers': markersGroup,
  'Show OSRM route geometry': routesGroup
};

L.control.layers(null, overlays, { collapsed: false }).addTo(myMap);

var startMarker = L.marker(startPosition, { draggable: true })
  .on('dragend', sendOsrmRequest)
  .bindPopup('Start')
  .addTo(markersGroup);

var finalMarker = L.marker(finalPosition, { draggable: true })
  .on('dragend', sendOsrmRequest)
  .bindPopup('Finish')
  .addTo(markersGroup);

sendOsrmRequest();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#myMap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2em;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#myStatus {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1/dist/leaflet.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1/dist/leaflet-src.min.js"></script>

<div id="myStatus">Drag the 2 markers to calculate the OSRM route</div>
<div id="myMap"></div>
```